# convert action script 2 to action script 3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

OK I read the forums and seems like anyone asking about converting AS2 to AS3 gets flamed with posts like "why would you use AS2, just rewrite it in AS3 from scratch".  So please do not answer like this, I just need help figuring out this particular snippet of the code.  This is AS2, I have no clue what it is trying to do.

```
if (_root.components == undefined) {
     _root.components = "";
}
_root.components = _root.components + _root.getInstanceAtDepth(this.getDepth()) + " ";
```

I googled the individual methods 'getInstanceAtDepth' and 'getDepth', and understand they deal with the layering of the movie.  Trouble is '_root.components'.  If this is referring to a movieclip as 'root', then there is no method or property named 'components'.  You can put components on the stage and make them a part of the movieclip fla file but again this does not seem to explain what the code is doing.  Does anyone have any idea what _root could be referring to here, what object has a property 'components'?

Thanks,

Comment: In AS3 _root was changed to root

Comment: @FraserCrosbie yeh the .components seems to be the problem... I change _root to root and the compiler says "access of possibly undefined property components through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject

I guess if I knew what type of object 'root' was referring to then I could add the proper import statement

Comment: Doesn't matter what you think, asking to convert AS2 to AS3 is no different than asking to convert python to C#. The answer will always be the same: you can't convert so you have to start from scratch. The only reason people like you always ask to convert AS2 to AS3 is only because they both have "AS" in their name and one has '2' and the other '3' so surely it should be so easy to convert them just because of that '1' difference. You can whine all you want at the end you'll still gonna have to write it from scratch in AS3.

Comment: Voted down. As he says himself, he already googled this subject and the answers was always the same: "not possible so start from scratch". So he figured since he did not like those answers by posting again and simply asking to not post the same answer he will get a different one ... Just amazing.

Comment: @botmaster I googled looking for other people's answers to this question.

If you do not know the answer then do not waste my time replying.  Why did you even reply here just to hear yourself talk?

Comment: You are wasting your time by wishing the answer will be different somehow, it will not. There's no conversion possible, get over it.

Comment: @BotMaster this is the first time posting this question.  I assume you understand English.  Please reread my original post.  If you can not answer it then do not reply

Comment: I read just fine, you ask specifically to not post the ONLY answer to your question just cos that's not working out for you. You gonna get angry with every person telling you the same thing, then you'll get no answers at all and a few more down votes and this question will get lost in the stack and forgotten. Suit yourself. At the end you'll still not be able to convert AS2 to AS3, period.

Comment: @BotMaster Alright fine then answer this question What object in AS2 has a method called .components

if you can not answer that then please stop this useless discussion

Comment: There's no property or method called "components" in AS2. In AS2 the _root property is dynamic so you can add methods and properties to it at runtime. This is what this code is doing, adding that property "components" and giving it some value.

Comment: Thank you that helps in answering the question... I don't know why that took so much effort tho

Comment: @gt5364e I put an answer, take a look.

Comment: If you asked about understanding AS2 code that would have been easier too. Now creating an AS3 equivalent is possible but will not work the same way and would probably require that the entire system will be reworked and rethink completely. To start an AS3 root is not directly dynamic and would at the minimum require casting, etc ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you want to understand that AS2 code not to convert it.

That code is apparently used inside a component(Button, MovieClip)'s code and it's just trying to concatenate the name of that component to a global string (`_root.components`).

For example, if I've a button called `button` and a MovieClip called `movieclip`, when I execute that code using their `onPress()` functions, I'll get something like this :

```
_level0.button _level0.movieclip
```

Hope that can help.